# Java JDA Bot How to check if message is written by specific User

Tags: java, discord, bots

I want to make a command which some users are allowed to use, but somehow my checks do not work

```
 Member member = event.getGuild().retrieveMemberById("id").complete();

        if(event.getAuthor().isBot()) return;
        if(event.getMember() == member) { ... }
```

I also tried

```
Member member = event.getMemerById("id");
```

but non of this worked
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the id of the author directly:

```java
if (event.getAuthor().getId().equals("id")) {
  ...
}
```